# Trying to understand the grammar behind a sentence

Tags: grammar

I've been learning Japanese for a while now but I just can't break down how the first part of this sentence is related to the second:

> ここT大医学部に比べれば遥かにランクが落ちるとはいえ、僕もまた歴とした医大生であり、奇しくも脳神経外科学を専攻している。

As some of you can tell (I suppose), it's from Saya no Uta ; the part I don't get is ここT大医学部に比べれば遥かにランクが落ちるとはいえ, a comparison and then he talks about the fact that he's majoring in neurological surgery ? I don't get the relation between those two.

Comment: Where is "ここ"? Seems "ここ" refers to a different university than T大? What is the context?

Comment: @EddieKai I think the speaker is visiting T大. (What I don't get is 専攻. An 医学生 doesn't have specialty yet. Maybe the speaker is a grad student, or maybe the author is not good at medical education in Japan...)

Answer (score 1):

とはいえ means even though, or despite the fact that

The speaker's university rank is a lot lower than T大医学部. But they are still a med student and majoring at neurosurgery at that. So they are implying that they should also be taken seriously, or something like that.